# Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views hide the title bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image]

is it possible to hide the title bar(Entertainment) **but** not the titles of the tab views(top rated,games,movies)?

Comment: Google search, Google search google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try for Hiding title bar

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: Well this hides the title and icon but definitely not the ActionBar.

Comment: This shows the entertainment title bar and then it hides it.But I dont want it this way, the entertainment title should not show at all.

Comment: check answer, edited,I had missed  actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);